# How to setup kube-aggregator?

Tags: kubernetes

Using Kubernetes 1.6.4 and want to enable custom metrics for autoscaling but it require kube-aggregator, I did not find any doc to setup it and integrate with api servers. Any help 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need k8s 1.7+ version to use k8s API aggregator feature, and follow below github project which has all required files to setup a metrics server, custom metrics using Prometheus adaptor

https://github.com/pawankkamboj/k8s-custom-metrics